# Strange error C2039: 'newFUN' : not able to add new member function in DLL class

Tags: c++

I am  facing strange problem,I have an existing class in a DLL (we can call as DLL A), I tried to add new member function but it gives error in DLL  B  (error C2039: 'NewFUN': is not a member of), all other members I can access but not new one. DLL C can access newly added member function also.it is not giving any error. what would be the reason? tried clean build etc but not resolving the issue. (Visual studio 10)